# Where does this PrimeNG element get its color and how do I change it?

Tags: css, angular, primeng, angular17, clarity

I am working on an Angular 17 project with the Clarity and PrimeNG libraries for styling. I have included the following css files in my angular.json:

- "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/mdc-dark-indigo/theme.css",
- "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",

The style works but I need to adjust it slightly to adhere to the style of the rest of the product.
I am using a basic PrimeNG TabView component:

```
<div class="recipe">
  <div class="tabs">
    <p-tabView>
      <p-tabPanel header="Settings">
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
              <div class="expanded-click-area" routerLink="settings">
                  <fa-icon [icon]="faCog"></fa-icon>
                  Settings
              </div>
          </ng-template>
      </p-tabPanel>
      <p-tabPanel header="Phases">
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
              <div class="expanded-click-area" (click)="navigateToRoute('phases')">
                  <fa-icon [icon]="faTasks"></fa-icon>
                  Phases
              </div>
          </ng-template>
      </p-tabPanel>
      <p-tabPanel header="Overview">
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
              <div class="expanded-click-area" (click)="navigateToRoute('overview')">
                  <fa-icon [icon]="faPieChart"></fa-icon>
                  Overview
              </div>
          </ng-template>
      </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

I specifically want to change the bottom border with color #9FA8DA as shown in this print screen:
[image: bane of my existence]

In my devtools I have turned off everything with border but it did not change anything, I also have replaced all 183 instances of #9FA8DA with white in node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/mdc-dark-indigo/theme.css and found none to replace in node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css. This did now change the color of the element even after a rebuilt of the page.

Where does this PrimeNG element get its color and how do I change it?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying an existing theme, which seems tedious, checkout the documentation for custom themes

[Primeng custom theme](https://primeng.org/theming)

Themes are created using [`primeng-sass-theme`](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-sass-theme) do check it out, hope it solves your issue!

Comment: Thanks! I did find that but I have no clue on how to start learning to use that

Comment: @NiggySagan [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAapJf6q1cw) better to go this route, than try to modify an existing one!

Comment: I will check it out! thanks! I still want to know how to change this element color, it is the last thing and then the menu is perfect :')